# Can you use Enum for Double variables?

Tags: c#, enums

I have created a class for handling Unit Conversion in C#. It is not working as it should only returning strings.

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace RestaurantManagementSystem
{
    class unitHandler
    {
        public enum Units
        {
            Grams = 1,
            KiloGrams = 0.001,
            Milligram = 1000,
            Pounds = 0.00220462,
            Ounces = 0.035274,
            Tonnes = 0.000001,

            Litres = 1,
            Millilitres = 1000,
            Cups = 4.22675,
            FluidOunces = 33.814,
            TeaSpoon = 202.884,
            TableSpoon = 67.628,
            CubicFeet = 0.0353147,
            CubicInch = 61.0237,
            CubicCentimetres = 0.0001,
            CubicMetres = 0.001

        }

        public double Convert_Value(Units from, Units to, double quantity)
        {
            double converted_quantity = 0;

            double fromValue = quantity * Convert.ToDouble(from.ToString());

            converted_quantity = fromValue * Convert.ToDouble(to.ToString());

            return converted_quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

I would somehow want the enum type to contain the double values of conversion factors of each unit then use them for conversion and returning the converted quantity.

Comment: No, but you can interpret integers are fixed point numbers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, The default type for [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is `int` or `long` and you could not use fractional numbers with it. You can use a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or class intead of enum for double

```
public struct Units
{
        public const double Grams = 1;
        public const double KiloGrams = 0.001;
        public const double Milligram = 1000;
        public const double Pounds = 0.00220462;
        public const double Ounces = 0.035274;
        public const double Tonnes = 0.000001;
        // Add Remaining units / values
}
```

And use it like

```
double d = Units.KiloGrams;
```

Comment: This code snippet is very confusing... (after edit, it still makes no sense!)

Comment: At least use a static class with constants.

Answer (score 5):

Nope:

I tried giving this to Visual Studio:

```
public enum Test : double
{
    Hello, World
}
```

And it said:

> Type byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong expected

Answer (score 3):

You can't use float/double with enums. You may have to define constants.

```
public const double KiloGrams = 0.001;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, can't be done. Enums are strictly integers/bytes. Really, they are supposed to be their own type.

You can try:

```
enum Units() {
    Grams ,
    KiloGrams ,
    Milligram 
}

public function GetUnitsFloatValue(Units unit) : float
{
    switch (unit)
    {
        case Units.Grams :
            return 1;
        case Units.KiloGrams :
            return 0.001;
        case Units.MilliGrams:
            return 1000;           
    }

    //unhandled unit?
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `double` to a `long` using the `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(double)` method before hand and hardcode them into an enum with the backing `long` type. Then you would have to convert the enum value back to a `double`.

It is probably more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use enum with doubles. You can only use it with `int` and `long`