# Having created an enum, how would I be able to assign them a decimal type value in a get method?

Tags: c#, enumeration

I am trying to create a program in where I am trying to give/assign a created enumeration list, a monetary value to be returned. However I am unsure how I can do this.

````
 public decimal GetAccessoriesCost()
     {
                ?????????
        }

public enum Accessories
    {
        None,
        StereoSystem,
        LeatherInterior,
        StereoAndLeather,
        ComputerNavigation,
        StereoAndNavigation,
        LeatherAndNavigation,
        All
    }```

I want Stereo to be 20.20
and Leather to be 10.10
````

Comment: `enum`s can only be of *integral* type, which decimals aren't a part of. You can however create a `Dictionary<Accessories, decimal>` to store the costs

Comment: You also very likely want your enum to be a `[Flags]` type so you dont have to specify every combination such as `SteroAndLeatherAndNavigationAndGPSAndAntiTheftAndFoo`. An enum is not really ideal for this use case

Comment: I am not sure that is the best duplicate. I think a duplicate explaining how to have prices in a dictionary keyed by an enum may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The enums in C# (unlike Java) have to be cardinal (something that is basically an integer or a whole number). see this answer for more details [Can you use Enum for Double variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744123/can-you-use-enum-for-double-variables)

The reason enums have this constraint is to be closer to c++ and c where the enums are a fancy way to group integer constants in a namespace and probably generate a sequence.